# Under what conditions an subspace of a CDH space is CDH?

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is countable dense homogeneous (CDH) if it is separable, and for every pair $(D,E)$ of countable dense subsets of $X$ there exists a homeomorphism $f:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f(D) = E$.

Unless I'm wrong, being a CDH is not hereditary. I was working a while on it and I think that if $X$ is CDH and $ Y\subseteq X$ then at least it is necessary that $Y$ be dense in $X$ so that it "can" be CDH, although I think it is not enough.

Do you have an idea of what conditions I need?

Comment: Every countable dense subset of $Y$ can be extended to a countable dense subset of $X$ (just add on a countable dense subset in $X- Y$), so certainly a sufficient condition might be that we can extend any of the homeomorphisms described above $Y \to Y$ to a homeomorphism on $X$ which is compatible with the dense subsets. Although I think in general the question of whether you can extend homeomorphisms on a subset to the whole space is a hard question.

Comment: @desiigner Since the goal is to prove that "$X$ CDH implies $Y$ CDH" (not conversely), the part of your comment about extending self-homeomorphisms of $Y$ to self-homeomorphisms of $X$ should rather be about restricting self-homeomorphisms of $X$ to self-homeomorphisms of $Y$ (and that looks hopeless, since a self-homeomorphism of $X$ could map $Y$ to a totally different part of $X$).

Comment: A connected CDH space is homogeneous, so that restricts the class of subsets to consider quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Henno, do you have a reference for the proof of this affirmation " A connected CDH space is homogeneous," ?

Answer (score 1):

There are dense subsets of CDH-spaces that are not CDH. In fact, remember that $\mathbb{R}$ is CDH (back and forth). But $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, non-discrete and not CDH. Because, we have the following

**Theorem 1. Let $X$ be a non-discrete CDH space, then $\aleph_{1}\leq |X|$.**

****Proof.****      Suppose otherwise, $X$ is countable. As $X$ is non-discrete, there is $x_{0}$ be a non-isolated point of
$X$ (that is, $\{x_{0}\}$ is not open). Note that $X$ and $X\setminus \{x_{0}\}$ are countable and dense in $X$, then there is $h\in\mathcal{H}(X)$ such that $X=h[X]=X\setminus \{x_{0}\}$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed CDH is not hereditary: $[0,1]$ is not CDH but a subspace of the CDH space $\Bbb R$ (all usual topology).

I don't think there is an easy condition to ensure that a subspace still is CDH. It's quite a strong condition.

Comment: Hi, Henno. I am new to the study of CDH topological spaces, How do you show that $[0,1]$ is not CDH?

Comment: Another example that may serve is the following $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a CDH space. In fact, suppose otherwise, that is, $\mathbb{Q}$ is CDH. Consider the two countable dense subsets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$  of $\mathbb{Q}$ then there is an autohomeomorphism $h:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}=h[\mathbb{Q}]=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, contradiction.

Comment: @user987 A CDH space is in particular homogeneous while $[0,1]$ is not: any homomorphism of $[0,1]$ must fix the set $\{0,1\}$. So either $h(0) = 0, h(1)=1$ or $h(0)=1, h(1)=0$ must happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henno. Maybe another example may serve is the following : $[-1,1]$ is not CDH. In fact otherwise, $[-1,1]$ is homogeneous, then there exists an autohomeomorphism $h:[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ such that $h(-1)=0$, then $h|_{]-1,1]}:]-1,1]  \to [-1, 0[ \cup ] 0,1] $ is also a homeomorphism, a contradiction.

Comment: @user987 that’s the same example as all closed intervals in $\Bbb R$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Great, well thanks @Henno. But the fact is that: If $X$ is CDH, connected and first countable. Then $X$ is homogeneous.

Comment: @user987 true, but we don’t even need that fact, as we can just use countable dense sets, one of which contains the boundary points and one who does not.

Comment: I understood, you are right. Thank you very much for the help.